# How to curl elasticsearch kubernetes operator without passing -k over tls?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Hello ElasticSearch Champs,

I deployed EK from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html on Kubernetes.

I Am unable to curl ElasticSearch without -k option!

```
curl --cacert ca-bundle.crt -u "elastic:9sg8q9h4tncvdl2srqiptn9z" "https://10.4.1.14:9200"

    curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
    More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

        curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
         of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
         bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
         using the --cacert option.
        If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
         the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
         problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
         not match the domain name in the URL).
        If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
         the -k (or --insecure) option.
        [root@quickstart-es-default-0 certs]#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to connect elasatic search using curl without -k option.

i.e. `curl --cacert public-http.crt -u "elastic:9sg8q9h4tncvdl2srq9ptn9z"  "https://35.193.165.24:9200"`

Note: in above **public-http.crt** is the **ca.crt**(**CA**) in <**clustername**>**--es-http-certs-public** like **quickstart-es-http-certs-public** secret(**kubectl get secrets -all-namespaces**)

This can be resolved by passing the kubernetes cluster-IP/loadbalancer/server-hostname(**DNS**) from which you are running curl command in the **kind:Elasticsearch** manifest under **subjectAltNames** as shown below:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f 
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.6.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        subjectAltNames:
        - ip: 10.4.0.16
        - dns: logstash
        - ip: 10.4.0.14
        - ip: 10.8.0.117 
        - ip: 35.193.165.24
        - dns: localhost
EOF
```

==========================================================================

```
root@logstash:/certificates/espod# curl --cacert public-http.crt -u "elastic:9sg8q9h4tncvdl2srq9ptn9z"  "https://35.193.165.24:9200"
{
  "name" : "quickstart-es-default-0",
  "cluster_name" : "quickstart",
  "cluster_uuid" : "H-ftq8B7Q6e4Swuq6mfDew",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f",
    "build_date" : "2020-03-26T06:34:37.794943Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
```

## }

**More references:**

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.7/ls-security.html#ls-http-ssl
2. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-tls-certificates.html